# Map names to codes and use mapping to replace names in other objects

Tags: r, mapping

Here is a representation of my data

A list of hospitals

```
ls_Hospital<-c("Hospital1", "Hospital2", "Hospital3", "Hospital4", "Hospital5") # a vector
```

I have another list of certain of hospitals with different parameters associated with them.

```
list_of_hospit_param<-list(Hospital1=c("A","B","C"), Hospital2=c("C","Z","E"),Hospital4=c("K"))
```

I Want to anonymize hospital names, by replacing them with codes

I firstly mapped hospital names to the codes:

```
codes<-c("A","B","C","L","Z","X")

hospital_mapping<-setNames(codes, ls_Hospital)
```

I now want to completely change the names of the hospitals and replace them with their corresponding code, in each of the data sets  `ls_Hospital` and `list_of_hospit_param`.

For example the `list_of_hospit_param` will be replaced by this:

```
list(A=("A","B","C"), B=c("C","Z","E"),L=c("K"))
```

Comment: I recommend you improve the quotation marks in your ls_Hospital definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(ls_Hospital <- c(
  "Hospital1", "Hospital2",
  "Hospital3", "Hospital4",
  "Hospital5"
))
(list_of_hospit_param <- list(
  Hospital1 = c("A", "B", "C"),
  Hospital2 = c("C", "Z", "E"),
  Hospital4 = c("K")
))

(codes <- c("A", "B", "C", "L", "Z", "X"))

hospital_mapping <- setNames(codes, ls_Hospital)

# make an ls_Hospital_2 from renaming ls_Hospital by the hospital mapping
(ls_Hospital_2 <- unname(hospital_mapping[ls_Hospital]))

# make an list_of_hospit_param_2 from renaming list_of_hospit_param by the hospital mapping
list_of_hospit_param_2 <- list_of_hospit_param
(nms_1 <- names(list_of_hospit_param_2))
names(list_of_hospit_param_2) <- unname(hospital_mapping[nms_1])

list_of_hospit_param_2
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use the named vecotr `hospital_mapping` as a lookup:

```
ls_Hospital <-  hospital_mapping[ls_Hospital]

# see comments @M-- 
ls_Hospital <- unname(ls_Hospital)

names(list_of_hospit_param) <- hospital_mapping[names(list_of_hospit_param)]
```

```
1.
Without uname
Hospital1 Hospital2 Hospital3 Hospital4 Hospital5 
      "A"       "B"       "C"       "L"       "Z" 

With uname: 
"A" "B" "C" "L" "Z"


2. 
$A
[1] "A" "B" "C"

$B
[1] "C" "Z" "E"

$L
[1] "K"
```

Comment: `ls_Hospital` still shows the names, so not entirely anonymized. Add `unname` : ```ls_Hospital <-  unname(hospital_mapping[ls_Hospital])```